Flutter - Retry token with graphql_flutter?
I'm working with GraphQL (graphql_flutter) in Flutter and I want to handle token expiration by retrying the request with a new token. I've added ErrorLink to my setup but I'm unsure how to correctly make another API request to fetch the new token and update the GraphQL client.
here is the code below
import 'package:graphql_flutter/graphql_flutter.dart';


final authLink = AuthLink(getToken: _getToken);


final HttpLink httpLink = HttpLink(
 'https://testapi.com/graphql',
);


final ErrorLink errorLink = ErrorLink(
 // onGraphQLError: (req, forward, res) async* {
 //   yield* forward(newReq);
 // },
);


//final Link link = errorLink.concat(authLink.concat(httpLink));
final Link link = Link.from([authLink, httpLink]);


final gqlClient = GraphQLClient(
 link: link,
 cache: GraphQLCache(store: InMemoryStore()),
);


Future<String?> _getToken() async {
 return 'Bearer token';
}

